# Ruby on Rails Remember Me Log In Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

I am following the following tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

And have just tried to add the 'remember me' functionality, so only up to around 4 minutes of the tutorial.

**Everything seems fine but once I try to log in it just goes back to the home page and no one is logged in.**

User.rb:

```
before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) 

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

sessions_controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by email: params[:email]
    if user and user.authenticate params[:password]
        # 'logging in' is performed by saving a user's id in the session variable
        #session[:user_id] = user.id
        #cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        if params[:remember_me]
          cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        else
          cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        end
        # redirect to last page or root_path (products/index.html.erb')
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash.now.notice = "Invalid user/password"
        render :new
    end
end


def destroy     
    # the act of logging out is performed by simply setting the key (:user_id)      
    # in the session hash to a value of nil (nothing)                   
    #session[:user_id] = nil
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)     
    # redirect to root_path (products/index.html.erb') 
    redirect_to root_path 
end
```

application_controller:

```
def authenticate_user
    # if session[:user_id]
        # @current_user = User.find session[:user_id]
    # else
        # @current_user = nil
    # end
    if cookies[:auth_token]
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) 
    else
        @current_user = nil
    end
end

def logged_in?      
    not session[:user_id].nil?  
end
```

views/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<!-- DRAW HTML CONTENT FOR PAGE -->
<%= form_tag sessions_create_path, :method => :get do %><div id='wrapper'>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <h1 class="page_header">THOR CINEMAS:<div class="file_selector"><span class="darker">LOG IN</span></div></h1>
            <div id="content">
                <!-- FULL PAGE CATEGORY CONTAINER -->
                    <div class='category'>
                        <div class='large_panel'>
                           <%= image_tag "thor_hammer.jpg",:size => "900x250" %>
                           <h1>Log IN:</h1><table>
                           <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="300px">
                                                <div class='info'>
                                                    <%= label_tag :email,'EMAIL:' %>
                                                </div> 
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                               <div class='info'>
                                                   <%= label_tag :password, 'PASSWORD:' %>
                                               </div> 
                                           </td>
                                           <td></td>
                                           <td></td>
                                       </tr>

                                       <tr>
                                              <td style="padding-right:45px"><%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] , :autofocus => true, :size => 42 %> </td>
                                              <td style="padding-right:45px"><%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password], :size => 42 %></td>
                                               <div class="field">
                                                  <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me] %>
                                                  <%= label_tag :remember_me %>
                                                </div>
                                       </tr>

                                    </table><br><p style="color:red"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> 
                                                <div class='info'>
                                                    OPTIONS:
                                                </div> 
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><%= submit_tag "Login" %></br></td>
                                            <td><%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table><br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div><% end %>
</body>   
</html>
```

Films_controller:

```
def index
    @films = Film.all
    if logged_in?
        @colour = Perference.find_by(user_id: session[:user_id]).colour
    end
end
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is.

Comment: Could you show me the code from your login form also.

Comment: @MenelikTucker I have added the view code

Comment: From what I understand everything should work fine, it seems that your password is not being inputted correctly.

Comment: See its weird, if I add the line `session[:user_id] = user.id` into the create method in the sessions_controller like the following: `if params[:remember_me]
     cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
     session[:user_id] = user.id
   else` it works fine. But to do the remember me functionality I don't want this line in the method

Comment: `cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token session[:user_id] = user.id` is all one line?

Comment: No, sorry I should have formatted that better, its two lines

Comment: Well then it might be in whatever controller your index action method is in, it may be checking for the `session[:user_id]` still as oppose to your `cookies[:auth_token]` and since you are no longer setting your `session[:user_id]` it is redirecting you to the login page.

Comment: Show me the controller your index.html.erb is inside.

Comment: I don't have a controller for the sessions, but I've uploaded the index method for the films_controller (which is the default page)

Comment: Do you have a  before_filter in your film controller that validates the existence of the `session[user_id]`?

Comment: No I don't have anything like that, the only thing I can find that seems similar is in the users_controller I have the code: `def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: From what I understand is that your are being redirected to your root_path (index.html.erb) and everything is working fine. What is actually happening is that something is redirecting you back to your login page for some reason after all this. Can you show me your `logged_in?` method.

Comment: Ok, I've just added that in the original question

Comment: I'm going to assume when you said, its going back your your home page and no one is logged in. The home page is your index.html.erb. But when you check for when someone is logged in, you are checking the `session[user_id]` not the `cookie[:auth_token]`. Your `logged_in?` method should have `!cookie[:auth_token].nil?`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75032/discussion-between-menelik-tucker-and-benjs-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are still utilizing the `session[:user_id]` throughout your controllers, you need to change the use `session[:user_id]` to `cookie[:auth_token]`. The places where you use the `session[:user_id]` for the current user's id, you can write:

`user_id = User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]).id`